# Oddly formatted page when following SO email link

Tags: bug, design

I got an email from Stack Overflow which I followed to the site by clicking the button `Create a job alert`

The link I followed to the page is oddly squished to the side, and the footer reaches all the way to the top. Simply refreshing the page will cause this to change to a more normal looking page, but with some changes in content.

I am viewing on chrome with windows 10

[image]

The full link address was https://itr-links.stackoverflow.email/u/click?_t=3603a3d8f3104ca5bd7015a5845f7fb7&_m=a441ceea4c4c48b890cdd4bda57dd6dc&_e=SlG7dKRb43ciNZppfhJs-9OrFdwofqmqAzqOas7ciwy5SN4y5IZTE8PIwjg5LxvhcydqDcC6XMCUUFkceBxH9aZKl_I7GlgJQofR7v-mbdZnfpmufSfnpQuDagbKmUCWvt5oAw3Epb1LOsjIS7VtbJhbPuRuFBlNdbubgq4BOxoQOWCmjhS4mIOd1pgikD4_x22NV0F71d-byQzOXwPonawQlTTLBKFJ6R-qk8KO-206M02oBfTc0iXVSWksc2-bx5dRPlhrgJYttBjk6Z_CT9gl60s32Hmn4rT2jdO6Ifh79orJ98-Ow9MXqWvCfMmcTOJV1DFXQA8QeQsCcCBSTMIsOfc9IjsAVw-y0BZAHkLUgbALcM14Kw1Jk6LsQ4ARKTLPQfllFsXPNVm0u2ZaYAw3OosnxkD6_mdp40bTNFPGWp7xtLIFZLKcdykWe93Lmp2jld7J4Ghc5sg51UFnVQ%3D%3D

Note that I am signed in to my account so it might not let others see the page

I opened the link multiple times with the same result

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it might be the correct site, but your browser couldn't get a CSS file. On the next attempt it might have been able to fetch that. Can you post the link from email in the question?